# Image of a generalized curve

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to show the image of a generalized cone through the Gauss map is a curve in $S^2$.

Could you give me some hints how wie could show that?

$$$$

[image]

Comment: Could you define generalized cone?

Comment: I added some information of the book about the generalized cone... Could you take a look at it? @FrancisBegbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we have
$$\mathbf{\sigma}_u = (1+v)\gamma',$$
$$\mathbf{\sigma}_v = \gamma-\mathbf{v},$$
$$\mathbf{\sigma}_u\times\mathbf{\sigma}_v = (1+v)\gamma'\times(\gamma-\mathbf{v}),$$
so a unit normal to the surface is given by 
$$\frac{\gamma'\times(\gamma-\mathbf{v})}{|\gamma'\times(\gamma-\mathbf{v})|}$$
when the patch is regular, which is a curve in $S^2.$

Comment: Why is this a curve in $S^2$ ?

Comment: It only depends on $u$ now.

Comment: I see... And why is that curve in $S^2$ ?

Comment: I divided by the norm, so it's of unit length.

Comment: $S^2$ is the unit sphere, right? So since $S^2$ is unit and the curve is also unit, we conclude that the curve is in $S^2$. Have I understood it correctly?

Comment: We have to conclude also that the cone has zero Gauss curvature. How do we conclude to hat?

Comment: Yep, and the total Gauss curvature is the area of the image under the Gauss map. A curve takes up zero area, hence the total Gauss curvature is zero.

Comment: I understand!! Thank you so much!! :-)